# AAPT: error: unexpected element <adaptive-icon> found in <manifest>

Tags: android, react-native, adaptive-icon

I am trying to use adaptive icon in react native android but it product following error.

> AAPT: error: unexpected element  found in

here is my manifes.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" package="com.anar">

  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW" />   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />



  <application android:name=".MainApplication" android:label="@string/app_name" android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher" android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round" android:allowBackup="false" android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:screenOrientation="portrait" android:launchMode="singleTop" android:name=".MainActivity" android:label="@string/app_name" android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize" android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
      <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
      </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name="com.facebook.react.devsupport.DevSettingsActivity" />
    <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY" android:value="MY_API_KEY_IS_HIDDEN"/>
    <service android:name="io.invertase.firebase.messaging.RNFirebaseMessagingService">
      <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT" />
      </intent-filter>
    </service>

    <service android:name="io.invertase.firebase.messaging.RNFirebaseBackgroundMessagingService" />

  </application>

  <adaptive-icon xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <background android:drawable="@color/ic_launcher_background" />
    <foreground android:drawable="@mipmap/ic_launcher_foreground" />   </adaptive-icon>



</manifest>
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You have already apply `adaptive-icon` using `android:icon` and `android:roundIcon`. Try to remove those extra code from `AndroidManifest.xml`

```
<application
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    ...>

<!--<adaptive-icon xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <background android:drawable="@color/ic_launcher_background" />
    <foreground android:drawable="@mipmap/ic_launcher_foreground" />   
</adaptive-icon> -->
```

If you check inside `ic_launcher_round.xml`, you will see those code there, If not then follow below steps to create one:

1. Create a folder `mipmap-anydpi-v26` under `res`
2. Create a file `ic_launcher_round.xml` under `mipmap-anydpi-v26`
3. Place below code inside `ic_launcher_round.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<adaptive-icon xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <background android:drawable="@color/ic_launcher_background"/>
    <foreground android:drawable="@drawable/ic_launcher_foreground"/>
</adaptive-icon>
```

**Update:** I have checked the resources that the site provide, It contains every things, just remove `adaptive-icon` related code from `AndroidManifest.xml` and **keep in mind that adaptive icon only works from API level 26**

Check [official documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/practices/ui_guidelines/icon_design_adaptive#creating_adaptive_icons_in_xml) for more details

Comment: I am following this web app to generate icon and as it says I should put both of them
https://easyappicon.com/#infoModalAndroid

Comment: and if I remove those parts then I am actually not using adaptive

Comment: so it already have <adaptive-icon .....  inside mipmap-anydpi-v26/ic_launcher_round.xml

Comment: Yes, remove it from `manifest` and manually check the file `mipmap-anydpi-v26/ic_launcher_round.xml`